# ArangoDB, query performance difference related to selectivity?

Tags: arangodb

I have a typical Movie domain with a bunch of movies and stars, which have a many to many relationship between each other.

When I run a query for movies with Star A and Star B, it responds in ~4ms while a very similar query for movies with category A and category B responds in ~150ms.  The queries are structurally identical (from what I can tell), with the only major difference being the selectivity % between the respective indexes that are used.

Here are the execution plan's of the two queries:

---

**The "fast" one...** looking for movies with both Star A and B:

```
Query string:
 FOR m IN INTERSECTION (
     (FOR s2m IN `Movie-Star` FILTER s2m._from == 'Star/12962' RETURN s2m._to),
     (FOR s2m IN `Movie-Star` FILTER s2m._from == 'Star/5001' RETURN s2m._to)
 )
 RETURN m

Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType            Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode          1   * ROOT
  8   SubqueryNode           1     - LET #1 = ...   /* const subquery */
  2   SingletonNode          1       * ROOT
 19   IndexNode              8         - FOR s2m IN Movie-Star   /* edge index scan */
  6   CalculationNode        8           - LET #9 = s2m.`_to`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: s2m : Movie-Star */
  7   ReturnNode             8           - RETURN #9
 15   SubqueryNode           1     - LET #4 = ...   /* const subquery */
  9   SingletonNode          1       * ROOT
 20   IndexNode              8         - FOR s2m IN Movie-Star   /* edge index scan */
 13   CalculationNode        8           - LET #13 = s2m.`_to`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: s2m : Movie-Star */
 14   ReturnNode             8           - RETURN #13
 16   CalculationNode        1     - LET #15 = INTERSECTION(#1, #4)   /* simple expression */
 17   EnumerateListNode    100     - FOR m IN #15   /* list iteration */
 18   ReturnNode           100       - RETURN m

Indexes used:
 By   Type   Collection   Unique   Sparse   Selectivity   Fields               Ranges
 19   edge   Movie-Star   false    false        11.56 %   [ `_from`, `_to` ]   (s2m.`_from` == "Star/12962")
 20   edge   Movie-Star   false    false        11.56 %   [ `_from`, `_to` ]   (s2m.`_from` == "Star/5001")

Optimization rules applied:
 Id   RuleName
  1   move-calculations-up
  2   move-filters-up
  3   move-calculations-up-2
  4   move-filters-up-2
  5   use-indexes
  6   remove-filter-covered-by-index
```

---

**The "slow" one...** looking for movies with both Category A and B:

```
Query string:
  FOR m IN INTERSECTION (
      (FOR c2m IN `Movie-Category` FILTER c2m._from == 'Category/101' RETURN c2m._to), 
      (FOR c2m IN `Movie-Category` FILTER c2m._from == 'Category/102' RETURN c2m._to)
  ) 
  RETURN m

Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType            Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode          1   * ROOT
  8   SubqueryNode           1     - LET #1 = ...   /* const subquery */
  2   SingletonNode          1       * ROOT
 19   IndexNode              2         - FOR c2m IN Movie-Category   /* edge index scan */
  6   CalculationNode        2           - LET #9 = c2m.`_to`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: c2m : Movie-Category */
  7   ReturnNode             2           - RETURN #9
 15   SubqueryNode           1     - LET #4 = ...   /* const subquery */
  9   SingletonNode          1       * ROOT
 20   IndexNode              2         - FOR c2m IN Movie-Category   /* edge index scan */
 13   CalculationNode        2           - LET #13 = c2m.`_to`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: c2m : Movie-Category */
 14   ReturnNode             2           - RETURN #13
 16   CalculationNode        1     - LET #15 = INTERSECTION(#1, #4)   /* simple expression */
 17   EnumerateListNode    100     - FOR m IN #15   /* list iteration */
 18   ReturnNode           100       - RETURN m

Indexes used:
 By   Type   Collection          Unique   Sparse   Selectivity   Fields               Ranges
 19   edge   Movie-Category   false    false        49.60 %   [ `_from`, `_to` ]   (c2m.`_from` == "Category/101")
 20   edge   Movie-Category   false    false        49.60 %   [ `_from`, `_to` ]   (c2m.`_from` == "Category/102")

Optimization rules applied:
 Id   RuleName
  1   move-calculations-up
  2   move-filters-up
  3   move-calculations-up-2
  4   move-filters-up-2
  5   use-indexes
  6   remove-filter-covered-by-index
```

---

> Fast one:  574 results in .005 seconds.
>
> Slow one:  905 results in .161 seconds.

For reference, the collection sizes are...

> Movie Collection: ~101,000
>
> Star Collection: 101,271
>
> Category Collection: 2
>
> Movie-Star EDGE Collection: 746,494
>
> Movie-Category EDGE Collection: 113,698

---

Is this performance difference a result of the selectivity of category being close to 50%, or something else?  Can you ELI5 (explain like I'm 5) why one query is roughly 30 times longer than the other?

---

**UPDATE**

Based on suggestions from Nate.

I tried an anonymous graph query instead of querying the edge collection directly.  That appears to be slower, taking about ~450 ms.  Here's the query explanation:

```
Query string:
 FOR m IN INTERSECTION (
     (FOR v IN 1 OUTBOUND 'Category/101' `Movie-Category` RETURN v._id), 
     (FOR v IN 1 OUTBOUND 'Category/102' `Movie-Category` RETURN v._id)
 ) 
 RETURN m

Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType            Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode          1   * ROOT
  6   SubqueryNode           1     - LET #1 = ...   /* const subquery */
  2   SingletonNode          1       * ROOT
  3   TraversalNode          2         - FOR v  /* vertex */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND 'Category/101' /* startnode */  Movie-Category
  4   CalculationNode        2         - LET #7 = v.`_id`   /* attribute expression */
  5   ReturnNode             2         - RETURN #7
 11   SubqueryNode           1     - LET #4 = ...   /* const subquery */
  7   SingletonNode          1       * ROOT
  8   TraversalNode          2         - FOR v  /* vertex */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND 'Category/102' /* startnode */  Movie-Category
  9   CalculationNode        2         - LET #9 = v.`_id`   /* attribute expression */
 10   ReturnNode             2         - RETURN #9
 12   CalculationNode        1     - LET #11 = INTERSECTION(#1, #4)   /* simple expression */
 13   EnumerateListNode    100     - FOR m IN #11   /* list iteration */
 14   ReturnNode           100       - RETURN m

Indexes used:
 none

Traversals on graphs:
 Id   Depth   Vertex collections   Edge collections    Filter conditions
  3   1..1                         Movie-Category   
  8   1..1                         Movie-Category   

Optimization rules applied:
 none
```

I also tried a "group by" style query, counting the number of categories associated to the movie and filtering movies with two categories.  This is a bit of a hack in that I'm avoiding the intersection only because I know there are only two categories in existence.

Regardless, this took even longer to execute, taking ~600 ms.

Here's the query plan:

```
Query string:
 FOR x IN `Movie-Category` COLLECT movie = x._to WITH COUNT INTO counter FILTER counter == 2 
 RETURN movie

Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType                    Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode                  1   * ROOT
  2   EnumerateCollectionNode   113698     - FOR x IN Movie-Category   /* full collection scan */
  3   CalculationNode           113698       - LET #3 = x.`_to`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: x : Movie-Category */
  4   CollectNode                90958       - COLLECT movie = #3 WITH COUNT INTO counter   /* hash*/
  5   CalculationNode            90958       - LET #5 = (counter == 2)   /* simple expression */
  6   FilterNode                 90958       - FILTER #5
  8   SortNode                   90958       - SORT movie ASC
  7   ReturnNode                 90958       - RETURN movie

Indexes used:
 none

Optimization rules applied:
 Id   RuleName
  1   move-calculations-up
  2   move-filters-up
```

---

After re-reading Nate's first comment, I think he's right.  This has less to do with the selectivity and more to do with the shear difference in edge count between my two cases.  When looking for movies with two stars in common, the number of edges for the stars I selected were around 5000 each.  So the "fast" star query had to perform an intersection of two lists of approximately 5000 items.  In contrast, the category query nearly splits the movie domain evenly (and with little overlap).  That's about 50,000 items in each list which must be intersected.

Is the cost of an intersection operation M * N ?  (M and N being the size of the left and right operands respectively?)  If so, the my fast case is 5000^2 while my slow case is 50000^2.  The slow case is 100 times slower.

Thoughts?  Is that accurate or am I missing something?

Comment: I think this has something to do with your collection sizes. In your slow query, you have only two categories connecting to many movies. In your fast query, you have many movies and evidently many stars. Thus for each star, there are far fewer edges than there are for each category. You may be able to improve performance by structuring this query as a graph traversal rather than a collection scan.

Comment: @NateGardner I'll test that theory tomorrow by adding many more categories and testing the same query as the count increases.
How do I structure this as a graph traversal?  I thought I already had by using the edge collection type, which made this an 'anonymous graph' traversal.  Do I need to use the FOR operator format specific to graphs?
This is day 3 with ArangoDB for me; please forgive my naivety.

Comment: No problem! See this URL for anonymous graph syntax. I usually prefer named graphs because they're conceptually a little easier for me to track. https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0.8/AQL/Graphs/Traversals.html#working-with-collection-sets

Graph traversal looks like `for vertex[, edge[, path]] in [min[..max]] outbound|inbound|any startVertex edgeCollection1, ..., edgeCollectionN [options]`

That's somewhat different from the filtering you're doing,  where you're actually scanning the edge collection.

e.g. `for movie in outbound 'Category/101' 'Movie-Category' return movie`

Comment: Max Neunhoeffer has written a lot about the complexity of various ArangoDB operations. He would probably know about the complexity of the intersection operation.

https://github.com/neunhoef

Comment: @MaxNeunhöffer Max, any thoughts on this ArangoDB performance question?